# Converting Java to C#

Tags: c#, java

I have a Java file I'm converting to C#. I got most of it done, I'm just having trouble figuring out what this is supposed to be turned into. How can I convert this to C#?

(some of the code has been stripped to make it easier to read)

```
private GestureDetector.OnGestureListener mFlingRemoveListener =
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public final boolean onFling() {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

Comment: I'm wrong or it's Android?

Comment: @Servy - It does look like it is that one, but I'm still having trouble converting it correctly.

Comment: @vkapadia Sure, because you're asking for the C# implementation of a Java feature that C# simply didn't implement.  It doesn't exist.  There is no 1:1 mapping of that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
private GestureDetector.OnGestureListener mFlingRemoveListener = new SimpleOnGestureListenerAnonymousInnerClassHelper();

private class SimpleOnGestureListenerAnonymousInnerClassHelper : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    public override bool onFling()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on the downvote?  If SimpleOnGestureListener is an interface, this is how it's done.  You can use a lambda only if you're replacing the interface with a delegate - you might not have that freedom.

Comment: I don't know, I didn't downvote it. Your solution seems to work, I don't see anything wrong with it. Still finishing converting, if it works I'll accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't a lambda work?  Have your event listener be a delegate and then do

```
private GestureDetector.OnGestureListener mFlingRemoveListener = () => false
```